# Excel Bubble graph bubble name

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, graph, charts

I am having problem with bubble graph. as I know it is not possible to draw an bubble graph with pivot table so I created my bubble graph manually. But I want to put names to every bubble on chart which are in the same row. for example:

this is my pivot table

```
Cluster   Sales     Stock    Revenue 
A          10         2        100
B          12         5        120
C          5          1        50
```

I created bubble graph with: `X values=Sales`  `Y` `values = Stock`  `Bubble Size = Revenue`
now I want to see `Clusters (A/B/C)` on the top of the each bubble.

Also it would be great if the cluster name show up when I click with mouse,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free XY Chart Labeler add-in from Rob Bovey, available here:

http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm

Then you can either use the add-in to place the labels, or study the code to see how it's done in VBA

[image]

A manual way to achieve the same result is to add data labels to the bubbles and point them to the series name. Then manually edit each data label, click the formula bar, enter a = sign and click the cell that contains the desired text. The add-in doe basically the same thing, just automated.

Comment: Great. Would you take the trouble to mark this as the answer, so people can see that the question has been solved.